# how to implement dynamic tkinter listboxes?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was given some example code of how to essentially control multiple Listboxes within one function, it seems to work during the example code but after implementing i am struggling to see what I've missed out.

**Example code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class MultiListbox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        for i in range(5):
            lb = tk.Listbox(self, height=10, exportselection=False)
            lb.pack(side="left", fill="y")
            for j in range(10):
                lb.insert("end", f"Listbox {i+1} value {j+1}")
            lb.bind("<Double-1>", self.removeSeq)

    def removeSeq(self, event):
        lb = event.widget
        curselection = lb.curselection()
        index = curselection[0] if curselection else None

        for listbox in self.winfo_children():
            listbox.delete(index)
  
root = tk.Tk()
mlb = MultiListbox(root)
mlb.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Where I am trying to implement logic:

**Imports**

```
import tkinter as tk,tkinter.ttk as ttk, pyautogui, numpy, easygui, cv2, os, time, _thread, re, math, subprocess
from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
```

**Class**

```
class Acgm003App:
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        
        for i in range(5):
            self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.modeSelect)
            self.lb.configure(background='#2f2a2d', exportselection='false', font='{Arial} 12 {}', foreground='#feffff', height='23')
            self.lb.configure(relief='flat', width='12')
            self.lb.pack(side='left')
            for j in range(10):
                self.lb.insert("end", f"Listbox {i+1},{j+1}")
            self.lb.bind("<Double-1>", self.getIndexLB)
```

**Function**

```
    def getIndexLB(self, event):
        print('hello')
        self.lb = event.widget
        curselection = self.lb.curselection()
        index = curselection[0] if curselection else None

        for listbox in self.lb.winfo_children():
            print(index)
            listbox.delete(index)
    pass
```

I am just not getting anything back at all, I put `print('hello')` there just to make sure it was binded correctly, it prints just fine, but no result.

The code is intended to delete listbox items in other listboxes by taking the corresponding index of the curselection, sort of a work around to a tk.treeview.

Let me know if you can help!

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables - maybe it try to delete from wrong `listbox` and you don't see result.

Comment: you use `winfo_children():` in wrong way - original code use it on `frame` to find `listboxes` inside `frame` but you use it on `listbox` so you try to get some elements inside `listbox`. I think you need `self.modeSelect.winfo_children()` because you use `Listbox(self.modeSelect)` to put `listbox` inside `self.modeSelect`. OR you should keep all listoboxes on some list and then you would need `for listbox in list_of_all_my_listbox:`. It will be more useful if you will have other widgets in window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it but I think you use it with wrong object.

Original code use

```
lb = tk.Listbox(self, ...)
```

to add listbox to `self` and later it searchs `children` in `self`

```
for listbox in self.winfo_children():
```

You add listbox to `self.modeSelect`

```
tk.Listbox(self.modeSelect, ...)
```

so you should search `children` in `self.modeSelect`

```
for listbox in self.modeSelect.winfo_children():
```

---

But this method can make problem if you add other widgets in `self.modeSelect` because it will try to use `.delete(index)` also on other widgets. And then you should check if you get `tk.Listbox`

```
    for child in self.modeSelect.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, tk.Listbox):
            child.delete(index)
```

**EDIT:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Acgm003App:

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        
        self.modeSelect = tk.Frame(master)
        self.modeSelect.pack()
        
        # other child in `self.modeSelect`
        self.label = tk.Label(self.modeSelect, text="Hello World")
        self.label.pack(side='top')
        
        for i in range(5):
            self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.modeSelect)
            self.lb.pack(side='left')
            for j in range(10):
                self.lb.insert("end", f"Listbox {i+1},{j+1}")
            self.lb.bind("<Double-1>", self.getIndexLB)

    def getIndexLB(self, event):
        self.lb = event.widget
        curselection = self.lb.curselection()
        index = curselection[0] if curselection else None

        for child in self.modeSelect.winfo_children():
            # check if child is `tk.Listbox` or other widget
            if isinstance(child, tk.Listbox):
                child.delete(index)

root = tk.Tk()

app = Acgm003App(root)

root.mainloop()
```